# Git still thinks it's on an old version of the branch

Tags: git

I have a script that I wrote that creates users in AWS.

I fixed a few errors in the script, including one where it sends the new user the wrong login URL.

Committed and pushed to the repo. Did a git pull, just to make sure everything was current. Then the next day I used it for an actual user, and the script STILL sent the wrong URL.

Did a git pull again, and it claimed that everything was already up to date. Created a test user and the error still occurred.

Then I deleted the repo from my machine, cloned it again, and then created a new test user in AWS. That time the problem was fixed.

So why on Earth would git claim that it was already up to date, but have an old incorrect version of my script, before I deleted and re-cloned the repo to my machine?

Comment: Probably you forgot to fetch/update (update through merge/checkout/rebase/whatever) the branch to get latest changes from remote?

Comment: Shouldn't a git pull have sufficed?

Comment: It should... if you are using the right branches when running it.

Comment: Wrong branch? Wrong remote?

Comment: Nah, I had the right branch and remote. Just really odd behavior so I decided to post about it.

Comment: Does the remote origin server show the pushed commit? wether in github or any other git remote server? Can you provide the .git/config content of the non working git pull end server? Can you execute the next to debug what your git client is doing with: GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin <branch_name>